# How to use selenium to scrape from multiple page clicks

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a selenium script that will get all filenames in every directory on a website. My approach to that is to make a list of directory objects and .click() every directory in the list one by one to access all filenames. The problem I face is Selenium does not allow me to click on the next directory after the 1st. The following code is my approach...

```
folders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("directory")

for folder in folders:
    folder.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    # click below is to navigate back to root directory
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="default-layout"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ol/a').click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

With the above code, I get the following error when Selenium tries to click on the 2nd directory in the list...
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Sleeps are a bad practice... if you need a wait, add a `WebDriverWait` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By opening the link and going to another page the previously collected links become [stale](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/).
To overcome this problem you will need to collect the `folders` list again each time you are coming from the opened page back to the main page.
So, your code can be as following:

```py
folders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("directory")

for index, folder in enumerate(folders):
    folders[index].click()
    #do what you need to do on the opened page
    #then get pack to the main page
    #and collect the `folders` list again with
    time.sleep(2)
    folders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("directory")
```

Comment: Thank you @Prophet. For anyone looking at this in the future, just initialize 'index' at 0 before the loop

Answer (score 0):

This means that the element you are trying to click isn't in the DOM anymore.

A possible solution is to use `WebDriverWait` something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
secs = 2
def waitUntilFound(driver):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="default-layout"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ol/a')
    if element:
        return element
    else:
        return False
element = WebDriverWait(driver, secs).until(waitUntilFound)
```

Comment: Once element become stale it will never be back! Waiting for stale element reference will always end with `TimeoutException`

Comment: Also, your `else` will never be hit because if `element` doesn't exist the `.find_*` statement threw an uncaught exception which will cause the script to fail before ever getting to the `else`. The way to do this is to use `.find_elementS_*` (plural) and then check for an empty list.